# Cannot find module nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

My config.js file:

```
const config = {
    development: {
        PORT: 5000
    },

    production: {
        PORT: 80
    }
};

module.exports = config[process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()];
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=development && nodemon ./server.js",
    "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production && node ./server.js"
  },

"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
```

server.js file:

```
const config = require('./config/config');

app.listen(config.PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${config.PORT}...`));
```

The problem:

```
> cubicle@1.0.0 start C:\Users\stani\Documents\GitHub\Intro-to-JavaScript\Softuni\5. Back-end\3. ExpressJS & Templating\cubicle
> SET NODE_ENV=development && nodemon ./server.js

'Templating\cubicle\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\stani\Documents\GitHub\Intro-to-JavaScript\Softuni\5. Back-end\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cubicle@1.0.0 start: `SET NODE_ENV=development && nodemon ./server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cubicle@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stani\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-10T16_07_01_722Z-debug.log
```

I tried installing it globally and other stuff I read on the internet but it sum down to this error, I don't understand what seems to be the problem.

Comment: "set NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon ./server.js" try this !

Comment: I've used .trim() to get rid of the space at the end. Even if I remove the space and .trim() the problem still occurs.